# wget permission denied error

Tags: permissions, 20.04, wget, read-only

**Task:** Hi I am trying to download apache spark using wget. However I get error:

[image]

**Problem :** Permission denied.
**Reason:** No write permission for folder spark1
**What do I want:** How Do I enable write permission to the folder spark1.

Some posts have said that root owns the file , so I need to change permission from root. Below is the screenshot for root Should I give write permissions to folder spark1 from Root?

[image]

Comment: It's probably an ownership issue. Try `sudo chown -R shailaja:shailaja ~/spark1`.

Comment: Who owns the directory you are downloading in, and why do you download there ? Ibn what directory are you downloading?  There are probably a security reason for not every one can write in that directory.

Comment: Jos, your answer helped...pls write this as answer so that others can also benefit